# Выборка и объединение двух таблиц, с переносом совпадающих значений одной из таблиц, из строки в столбец результата

Tags: mysql

Есть две таблицы.

```
    users:
    
    | id        |     user       |     email          |
    | --------- | -------------- | ------------------ |
    | 1300      | user_nick      | user_nick@mail.com |
    | 1301      | user_tom       | user_tom@mail.com  |
    | 1302      | user_anna      | user_anna@mail.com |
    
    values:
    
    | field_id  |     user_id    |     value      |
    | --------- | -------------- | -------------- |
    | 1         | 1300           | Nick           |
    | 3         | 1300           | New York       |
    | 5         | 1300           | 555 555 55     |
    | 1         | 1301           | Tom            |
    | 3         | 1301           | Utha           |
    | 5         | 1301           | 555 555 66     |
```

Если я делаю запрос:

```
SELECT u.id, u.user, u.email, v.value FROM users u, values v WHERE v.user_id = 1300 AND u.id = 1300 AND (v.field_id = 1 OR v.field_id = 5);
```

закономерно возвращается такой результат:

```
    | id        |     user       |     email          |     value      |
    | --------- | -------------- | ------------------ | -------------- |
    | 1300      | user_nick      | user_nick@mail.com | Nick           |
    | 1300      | user_nick      | user_nick@mail.com | 555 555 55     |
```

Понятно, что его можно разобрать, и получить требуемую структуру... но интересно, а возможно ли создать один запрос, который вернёт, требуемую структуру? А именно:

```
    | id        |     user       |     email          |     1          |     5          |
    | --------- | -------------- | ------------------ | -------------- | -------------- |
    | 1300      | user_nick      | user_nick@mail.com | Nick           | 555 555 55     |
```

То-есть, чтобы первые ячейки строк из таблицы values преобразовались в дополнительные столбцы в результате запроса? Точно помню, что когда-то давно в визуальном редакторе запросов MS Aссess, что-то подобное делал, но сейчас дело имею с MySQL, и никак не могу сформировать запрос, и сформулировать поиск в гугле, чтобы найти подходящие примеры.
Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но к сожалению, по непонятной мне причине, не удаётся сохранить сообщение в обычной манере, поэтому пришлось всё обернуть в тег кода...

Comment: JOIN двух копий EAV-таблицы. Ну или условное агрегирование.

Answer (score 0):

Наткнулся на собственный вопрос, и решил отписаться о готовом решении:

```sql
SELECT
    id,
    user,
    email,
    username,
    v1.value Nickname1,
    v2.value Phone5
FROM users u
    LEFT JOIN values v1 on v1.item_id = u.id AND v1.field_id = 1
    LEFT JOIN values v2 on v2.item_id = u.id AND v2.field_id = 5
GROUP BY u.id
```

| id | user | email | Nickname1 | Phone5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1300 | user_nick | user_nick@mail.com | Nick | 555 555 55 |
| 1301 | user_tom | user_tom@mail.com | Tom | 555 555 66 |
| 1302 | user_anna | user_anna@mail.com | NULL | NULL |